# view all text row when AutoCompleteTextView sugested some contain goes out of display on rightside

Tags: android, text, autocomplete, textview, autocompletetextview

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/edtxt"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:completionThreshold="1"
</AutoCompleteTextView>
```

This is my autocompeteTextview.Some part is left which commented below.
I want to visible total row of list.which goes out of display

Comment: <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/edtxt"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:completionThreshold="1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/xtxt_mandatory"
        android:ems="10"
        android:dropDownHeight="200dp"
        android:hint="Enter Text To Search"
        android:popupBackground="#0FFF"
        android:dropDownWidth="match_parent"
         android:textColor="#000000" >

        <requestFocus />
 </AutoCompleteTextView>

Comment: what is query here. Your question is not clear..

Comment: sorry i am not familiar in english . I used  AutoCompleteTextView it work properly but when it suggested the dropdown list row by row.That row total row not visible in display because it long string

Comment: for example "Accounting Standards notified by Central Government under the Companies Act (applicable to the Companies)" this is my string when user just type "acco" AutoCompleteTextView dispay this string but some part of string is not visible. i want to display on display total string.

Comment: you have hardcoded the width as "280dp" so it will display with in that length only. make it to wrap_content.

Comment: @PadmaKumar right side to of AutoCompleteTextView one imagebutton.thats not problem when drop-down list come that string not total visible

Comment: Itry this and its work :   adapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,android.R.id.text1,strmanlst);

Answer (score 1):

Replace this:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/edtxt"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/xtxt_mandatory"
    android:completionThreshold="1"
    android:dropDownHeight="200dp"
    android:dropDownWidth="match_parent"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter Text To Search"
    android:popupBackground="#0FFF"
    android:textColor="#000000" >

    <requestFocus />

</AutoCompleteTextView>
```

with this:

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
    android:id="@+id/edtxt"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/xtxt_mandatory"
    android:completionThreshold="1"
    android:dropDownHeight="200dp"
    android:dropDownWidth="match_parent"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Enter Text To Search"
    android:popupBackground="#0FFF"
    android:textColor="#000000" >

    <requestFocus />

</AutoCompleteTextView>
```

Comment: :sorry still not work its problem about dropdwon list .List row not visible because of length of string .

Comment: i found the :answer adapter =  new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), **android.R.layout.two_line_list_item**,android.R.id.text1,strmanlst);